# Android Lazy loading without ListView

Tags: android, wordpress, android-layout, listview

I am looking to implement lazy loading in my app and I cannot seem to get it done. I've looked everywhere and nothing seems to be working.

My app is a news app making a SQL query to my wordpress website and getting the image URL and the article title associated to the image. The thing is I cannot use list views for this app because I want the first article to be a way bigger image that takes a third of the screen and the title placed on the image (the same way it is done in this image : http://iphone-apple.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/lequipe2-iphone.jpg).

To create the design I have used RelativeLayout. Each article is a RelativeLayout composed of an ImageView and a TextView.

My problem is that all of the tutorials I found on lazy loading for ImageViews on the internet are for ListViews.

I have tried AsyncTask but it did not work. It actually worked but it showed all of the images at the end of the load so I had a black screen for about 5-10 secs before showing the main activity.

Does anyone have any idea how I could proceed ?

Thanks a lot for all of your answers ! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are working with Native Emulator that work in slow environment.Install bluestack emulator or try to work on some android device

Comment: I am actually only testing on a real phone and it still does not work :(